# How to make a popup menu contribution on the editor to appear only when Package Explorer view is active

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I have this question about how to add a popup menu contribution on the editor but only when the Package Explorer view is active. I tried with "locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any"" but it apears on the editor no mater the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `popup:<viewID>` to add popup only to specific view.

```
"locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any""
```

can be seen from everywhere, so you have to add **visibleWhen** if you want to see it only in specific view.